# Media9 mp4 video not playing?

Tags: media9, video

I've got the below code, trying to play a video named 'CaseA.mp4'. I am using the media9 package. When I open the document up (have installed latest updates for flash and adobe', the error comes up saying that it cannot play (see attached). Any thoughts? Admittedly, I am new to this, apologies. I need the video the be able to play without having to separately download the MP4 video onto the hard drive, so if I am using completely the wrong code/package then please let me know!

```
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
  \includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,height=150pt,
  addresource=CaseA.mp4,
  flashvars={%
     [![source=CaseA.mp4% same path as in addresource!
%   &autoPlay=true%    % optional configuration
%   &loop=true%        % variables][1]][1]
  }  
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance, much appreciated.

Josh

Comment: **Hint:** Add `\documentclass` to make the code complete.

Comment: What is the `![` for? I do not see this in the example on page 20 of the manual (https://ctan.org/pkg/media9).